# How to apply two separate regular expressions in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a shell snippet that finds all external JavaScript scripts in thousands of random html pages, which use the `<script src="…"` paradigm to include said scripts, with absolute URLs:

```
find ./ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 \
    perl -nle 'print $1 \
        while (m%<script[^>]+((https?:)?//[-./0-9A-Z\_a-z]+)%ig);'
```

Since scripts could also be loaded dynamically within JavaScript itself, I'd like to expand my snippet to match any absolute URL-like string which ends in `.js`, and preferably appears within the `script` tags.  (This won't be 100% accurate, but would probably be good enough to find a few extra cases of external scripts.)

I'm thinking of something like `<script[^>]*>.*["']((((https?)?:)?//)?[-.0-9A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}/[-./0-9A-Z\_a-z]+\.js)`, and maybe also with `.*</script>` at the end.

A tricky part comes in ensuring that multiple mentions of `.js` within a `script` results in multiple matches (which the regex above won't do by itself), but also that the two expressions that I have don't match in a way as to result in two outputs from a single mention of a given `$1` matching string in the input.

What would be a good way to add this new regex to the perl snippet I have?

Comment: You're not going to find `<script> </script>` *in* the external js files themselves though? You'll find them all linked one after the other in the html page. The only thing I could see is parsing for jQuery's [.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), which would be a lot simpler in regex.

Comment: @r3mus, thanks for bringing `.getScript` to my attention, but if you already have jQuery, you're not very likely to be loading external scripts with it; the idea is to find stuff like embedded third-party script references which the author of the page simply copy-pasted to enable some sort of tracking or something.

Comment: Even so, you still won't find it between <script></script> tags. You might have better luck just looking for .js and back referencing until you find an invalid filename/path char?

Comment: @r3mus, I don't understand what you mean.  You realise this is all html files, and we're looking at javascript right within the html files?

Comment: The way you worded the question it looks like you're searching through the loaded .js files to search for *more* dynamically loaded .js files. Am I mistaken?

Comment: I would avoid using regexes here, and make a small program to parse the HTML and find the <script> tags and others this way http://stackoverflow.com/a/4598384/74585 perhaps combined with File::File::Rule to http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.33/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm help you search through all the directories of HTML files

Comment: @MatthewLock definitely a more reliable and comprehensive way to go - Mojo is excellent.  That said, if cnst has already built the script, changing it might be an unnecessary undertaking.

Answer (score 0):

> A tricky part comes in ensuring that multiple mentions of .js within a
>   script results in multiple matches (which the regex above won't do by
>   itself)…

This can be accomplished by splitting your contemplated regular expression in two - one part for the `<script>` tag, the other part for the `.js` matches - and invoking the parts in nested loops; that nesting is made possible by the modifier `c`, which prevents the current position in the line from being *reset after failure to match*, and the `\G` anchor, which *matches at the point where the previous `g` match left off*.

> … also that the two expressions that I have don't match in a way as to
>   result in two outputs from a single mention of a given `$1` matching
>   string in the input.

This is ensured by the first expression only matching within a `<script …>` tag and the second expressions only matching between `<script>` and `</script>` tags.

So, the `perl` part of your shell snippet could look like:

```
    perl -nle '
    print $1 while m%<script[^>]+((https?:)?//[-./0-9A-Z\_a-z]+)%ig;
    while (m%<script[^>]*>%ig)  # for each <script> tag
    {
     print $2 while m%          # allow multiple mentions of `.js`
     \G((?!</script>).)*?       # do not pass over </script>, be non-greedy
     ["'"'](((https?:)?//)?[-.0-9A-Za-z]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}/[-./0-9A-Z\_a-z]+\.js)
                     %ixgc      # c: keep the Current position for outer loop
    }"
```