# Perl Regex - Search and replace between tags only if string is in-between

Tags: regex, bash, perl

I'm trying to come up with a regex that will match the entirety of the tag that has "ThisIsImportant" (including the tags themselves), without matching either of the other ones:

```
<tag>
  <random attribute="ThisIsNotImportant" />
</tag>

<tag>
  <random attribute="ThisIsImportant" />
</tag>

<tag>
  <random attribute="ThisIsAlsoNotImportant" />
</tag>
```

So far I've got "<tag>.*?</tag>", but I don't know how to make it so that I only match the one with "ThisIsImportant". Can anyone provide some help?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: For clarity, I want to match the entirety of "<tag><random attribute="ThisIsImportant" /></tag>".

I am trying to do this in Bash using the perl executable, and am avoiding something like xmlstarlet because the environments I need to run the script on does not have access to this application.

Comment: Which programming language or tool are you doing this in?  Please edit your question and add the appropriate tag.

Comment: I have added the requested information

Comment: [You know that regex is particularly ill-suited to parsing HTML, right?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1072112)?  If you're programming in perl, is [XML::DOM](http://www.cgi101.com/modules/XML.dom.html) or [Mojo::DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4598384/1072112) not an option? If you're programming in bash, are you doing so by choice?  And .. what have you tried?  We can't help you fix code we haven't seen.

Comment: It has been said here over and over again, if you're processing XML then use an XML parser. Regular expressions are good for many things, but cannot process irregular syntaxes

Comment: What do you mean by `tags themselves` ? Are you looking for just the  _tag_ that has that attribute value, or are you looking for a closing tag, and all between as well ?

Comment: I'm doing this in Bash, calling the perl executable because it was a single find and replace I had to do, and I was hoping it'd be a simple thing... something like `perl -0pe "s/<tag>.*?ThisIsImportant.*?<\/tag>/<replacement><\/replacement>/sg"` is what I was hoping to get.

Comment: That pattern took too much, it matched from the first tag to the last /tag, which included many other things and not just the one that had "ThisIsImportant" inside.

Comment: I edited the question, as I think my example wasn't very good...When I tried `<tag>.*?ThisIsImportant.*?<\/tag>`, it ends up getting from the starting `<tag>` at the top of the file and finishes it at the `</tag>` after "ThisIsImportant". I am trying to figure out how to start the match from the `<tag>` that is immediately before "ThisIsImportant", and not any earlier than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the closest starting tag to `ThisIsImportant` use a negative
assertion on the tag itself.

`/<tag>(?:(?!<tag>).)*ThisIsImportant.*?<\/tag>/`

Formatted:

```
 <tag>
 (?:
      (?! <tag> )
      . 
 )*
 ThisIsImportant
 .*? 
 </tag>
```